# What happens to Java runtime errors

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Following on from this question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/37294/logging-why-and-what

I was wondering what actually happens to an error that occurs during the runtime of a Java Enterprise Edition applicaiton.
Does the JVM store a log of all the errors?
Or are the errors forgotten?

Answer (score 0):

It is contingent where the output is directed. If output is getting pushed to a console window then yes...it is all but lost. An enterprise application however would be making use of a logging framework to deal with all output thus rendering any exception available within the logs provided by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Application servers usually have a big catch-all net to mop up any unhandled exceptions. However, if an exception is allowed to bubble up without it ever hitting a `catch` close, the thread it came from will die and the exception will be passed to the thread's [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html), if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

an error happens when the program is running. and is being handled by exceptions.

Exceptions : ignore the error, handel the exception, and go back to method that was called.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer makes any sense.